# Unable to render data from API in React Native

Tags: react-native, return, map-function

I have an API as shown below:

```
[
{
"available_quantity": 500, 
"available_quantity_units": "Units", 
"product_name": "ABC", 
"product_price": "35.00", 
},
{
"available_quantity": 500, 
"available_quantity_units": "Units",  
"product_name": "XYZ", 
"product_price": "50.00", 
}
]
```

I am trying to display the data in React Native. The code for it is shown below:

```
  const showData = () => {
    kioskData.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>{item.product_price}</Text>
        </View>
      );
    });
  };
    
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {loading ? (
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color={COLORS.blue} />
      ) : (
        showData()
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

But the data is not displayed on the screen and there is no error as well. Please assist me to fix the issue. Thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot return component in map function:

```
kioskData.map((item, index) => {
  return <View>
    <Text>{item.product_price}</Text>
  </View>;
});
```

Comment: Hi btb. I have modified the showData method as per your suggestion. But its still the same. Edited my question to add return to the showData method.

Comment: You need 2 return, one for showData and one for map. You just removed the first one.

Comment: Thanks, Adding another return statement worked.